# How to encapsulate a package to rename keys defined in it?

Tags: pstricks, key-value

I use `pst-eucl` package and I am not so happy with the names defined for its keys (because the names are difficult to remember). 
I want to rename some of the keys for my own purpose by creating a new package wrapping the package. For example, I want to rename:

- `PtNameMath` to `PointLabelMath`.
- `PointNameSep` to `PointLabelSep`.
- `PosAngle` to `PointLabelAngle`.
- `PointName` to `PointLabel`.

Could you show me the new package wrapping `pst-eucl` with renamed keys above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define the new keys copying the action of the old ones:

```
\makeatletter
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelMath}[false]{\@nameuse{Pst@PtNameMath#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelSep}{\edef\psk@PointNameSep{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelAngle}{\edef\psk@PosAngle{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelAngleA}{\edef\psk@PosAngleA{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelAngleB}{\edef\psk@PosAngleB{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelAngleC}{\edef\psk@PosAngleC{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabel}{\def\psk@PointName{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelA}{\def\psk@PointNameA{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelB}{\def\psk@PointNameB{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelC}{\def\psk@PointNameC{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelSep}{\edef\psk@PointNameSep{#1}}
\makeatother
```

If you want to write a new package, say `pst-eucl-mod.sty`, it should have the following shape:

```
\ProvidesPackage{pst-eucl-mod}
\RequirePackage{pst-eucl}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelMath}[false]{\@nameuse{Pst@PtNameMath#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelSep}{\edef\psk@PointNameSep{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelAngle}{\edef\psk@PosAngle{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelAngleA}{\edef\psk@PosAngleA{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelAngleB}{\edef\psk@PosAngleB{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelAngleC}{\edef\psk@PosAngleC{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabel}{\def\psk@PointName{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelA}{\def\psk@PointNameA{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelB}{\def\psk@PointNameB{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelC}{\def\psk@PointNameC{#1}}
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointLabelSep}{\edef\psk@PointNameSep{#1}}
\endinput
```

The source can be found in the file `pst-eucl.tex`, if you want other names.

This new package doesn't accept the `old` option that can be passed to `pst-eucl`, I believe you don't need it.